# MPJ Express error I have never seen before

Tags: java, mpi

I am getting this runtime error:

```
MPJ Express (0.35) is started in the cluster configuration
Starting process <0> on <Tornado>
Starting process <1> on <Predator>
mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1> is less than length <2>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in Simple
Packer : count <1> is less than length <2>
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1259)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:29)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1>
 is less than length <2>
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1317)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1> is less than leng
th <2>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        ... 8 more
```

I do not understand what it means,

This is the code that is causing it:

```
import mpi.* ;

class PingPongVariousLengths {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        MPI.Init(args);
        int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int tag = 99;
        int maxlen = 104857600; //200 megabytes     104857600 characters * 2 bytes per character = 209715200 bytes total, or 200 megabytes
        int minlen = 1; // 2 bytes
        char [] sendbuff = new char [maxlen];
        char [] recvbuff = new char [maxlen];
        long speedKbps;
        long speedMbps;
        long durationseconds;
int MAX_LOOPS = 20;

for (int len = minlen; len <= maxlen; len *= 2) {
        if (myrank == 0) {
                durationseconds = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; i++) {
                        long startTime = System.nanoTime();           
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(sendbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                        long duration = endTime - startTime;
                        durationseconds = durationseconds + (duration* 10-9);
                }
                durationseconds = durationseconds / MAX_LOOPS;
                System.out.println("Average time for the ping to be sent and recived of " + (len*2) + " bytes is " + durationseconds + " seconds");
                double transferRateMb = ((len*524288.0) / durationseconds );
                System.out.println("average transferRate (megabytes) : " + transferRateMb + " megabytes per second");
        } else if (myrank == 1) {
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
        }
}

        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

What is causing the error and how can it be solved?

EDITTTTT

changed minlength to 2

```
import mpi.* ;

class PingPongVariousLengths {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        MPI.Init(args);
        int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int tag = 99;
        int maxlen = 104857600; //200 megabytes     104857600 characters * 2 bytes per character = 209715200 bytes total, or 200 megabytes
        int minlen = 2; // 2 bytes
        char [] sendbuff = new char [maxlen];
        char [] recvbuff = new char [maxlen];
        long speedKbps;
        long speedMbps;
        long durationseconds;
int MAX_LOOPS = 20;

for (int len = minlen; len <= maxlen; len *= 2) {//len=*2 doubles the ping size each time
        if (myrank == 0) {
                durationseconds = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; i++) {
                        long startTime = System.nanoTime();           
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(sendbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                        long duration = endTime - startTime;
                        durationseconds = durationseconds + (duration* 10-9);// Converts nanoseconds to seconds
                }
                durationseconds = durationseconds / MAX_LOOPS;
                 //double transferRate = ((len*2.0) / durationseconds ) ; //amount of data in bytes transferred in 1 second. Currently returning 0 for every result
                //System.out.println("transferRate: " + transferRate + " bytes per second");
                System.out.println("Average time for the ping to be sent and recived of " + (len*2) + " bytes is " + durationseconds + " seconds");
                double transferRateMb = ((len*524288.0) / durationseconds );
                System.out.println("average transferRate (megabytes) : " + transferRateMb + " megabytes per second");
        } else if (myrank == 1) {
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
        }
}

        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

and am getting this error :

```
PongVariousLengths
MPJ Express (0.35) is started in the cluster configuration
Starting process <0> on <Tornado>
Starting process <1> on <Predator>
mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <2> is less than length <4>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in Simple
Packer : count <2> is less than length <4>
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1259)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:25)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <2>
 is less than length <4>
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1317)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <2> is less than leng
th <4>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        ... 8 more
```

EDIT 2

Ok, so after a bit of trial and error i commented out '//len *= 2)' on line 19, with this commented out, the program would run but it run constantly at 2 bytes, and did not stop after the required 20 loops, so i think this is the issue, but how can this be solved ?

Comment: it is just the symbol }

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `minlen = 2`.

Comment: I have tried minlen = 2, same error, and it is 1 because 1 character is 2 bytes

Comment: @user2065929 The error says that `count` is `1`, if you now pass `count` as `2`, how could you possibly get the same error. Double check that you are not passing `1` as `count` anywhere.

Comment: ah sorry, i thought you ment something else, i have not changed the count, will try that now

Comment: @user2065929 but `len` is what you pass *as* `count`. If you do `minlen = 2`, then `len` starts at `2` and the `2` gets passed as `count` on first iteration.

Comment: added the error to the original question, along with the current code of minlen 2

Answer (score 0):

Your exception seems to be thrown by this [block of code:](http://raytracempj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MPJServer/src/mpi/SimplePackerChar.java)

```
  public void unpack(mpjbuf.Buffer mpjbuf, int length, Object buf,
                  int offset, int count) throws MPIException {

    if(count * numEls < length) {
      throw new MPIException ("Error in SimplePacker : count <"+
          (count*numEls)+"> is less than length <"+length+">");
    }
```

So it appears that `count * numEls` is less than `length`. And it all seems to lead to your `Recv()` call (what I assume to be line 29), either:

```
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
```

or

```
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
```

So the "count" (`len`) is less than the length (which is 2). You have `minlen` set to 1 (which isn't "2" like the comments say), try setting it to 2 instead.

Comment: Even after adjusting count he claims to get the same error :>

Comment: added the error to the original question, along with the current code

Comment: Ok added another edit, think i have found the issue but unsure how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you missed an inner loop which run from `i=0` to `MAX_LOOP` at the process with `rank=1`. Since outer loop is varying length your process with `rank=0` is sending message of `len=2` while process with `rank=1` is expecting message with `len=4` because it is in next outer loop iteration. If you insert print statements you will see that your first message have successfully completed. But for second iteration it is a miss match in length. Here is the code fix:

```
for (int len = minlen; len <= maxlen; len *= 2) {
        if (myrank == 0) {
                durationseconds = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; i++) {
                        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                        System.out.println("Processor 0 printing len="+len);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(sendbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                        long duration = endTime - startTime;
                        durationseconds = durationseconds + (duration* 10-9);
                }
                durationseconds = durationseconds / MAX_LOOPS;
                System.out.println("Average time for the ping to be sent and recived of " + (len*2) + " bytes is " + durationseconds + " seconds");
                double transferRateMb = ((len*524288.0) / durationseconds );
                System.out.println("average transferRate (megabytes) : " + transferRateMb + " megabytes per second");
        } else if (myrank == 1) {
                for(int i =0; i < MAX_LOOPS; i++){
                        System.out.println("Processor 1 printing len="+len);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
                        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
                }
        }
}
```